# drawer not covering actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, drawerlayout

i want to open a drawer such that it covers the Actionbar. i tried it using a parent linear layout and inside it i defined toolbar and drawerLayout and is working fine but the thing is i cant see the menu item there.. that is i can open drawer only by swiping left to right on the screen. if i define toolbar outside of the linear layout than the menu is showing but the actionbar is not covered by drawer. how to achieve both of them simultaneously? 
here is my xml file of Activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@color/white"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="variofitness.com.schedulekeeper.HomeActivity">
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
               android:name="variofitness.com.schedulekeeper.Fragments.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: use action bar inside DrawerLayout

Comment: Change your Root layout from LinearLayout to RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this way it will help

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="info.androidhive.materialdesign.activity.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) can you help me how to change the title of the Actionbar  on selected item  from drawer?

Comment: in your activity just use setTitle("your title");

Comment: i used **getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);** but it results in app crashing

Comment: just check the line number and check that the fragment you are trying to display is available or not?

Comment: the fragment is available, the thing is i have arrayAdapter and in its onlclickListener i am getting the selected fragment and its title, from there i used  **getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title)**. so the app is crashing.. if i remove that line than its showing fine with one title for all fragments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101874/discussion-between-newbiee-and-lakhan).

Answer (score 1):

```
Please modify your Xml:Put your action bar  inside the drawer or use drawer as parent layout:
```

Another sample code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_all_courses_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.activlearn.ui.AllCoursesActivity">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <include layout="@layout/home_tool_bar" />


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_all_courses" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <fragment
        android:name="com.activlearn.fragments.DrawerFragment"
        class="com.activlearn.fragments.DrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: i did that, and instead of covering the actionbar, it just didnt show up

Comment: @Newbiee I am just putting a suggestion to you. What is the main problem. But you have to manege your inner layout accordingly. It will show definitely.

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine if you get the structure of your layout correct. As per [this guidance here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#DrawerLayout):

> To add a navigation drawer, declare your user interface with a DrawerLayout object as the root view of your layout. Inside the DrawerLayout, add one view that contains the main content for the screen (your primary layout when the drawer is hidden) and another view that contains the contents of the navigation drawer.

So your DrawerLayout should be the root and have two direct children. You have three elements to include though, so you need to group your toolbar and content container together. In pseudo code, the structure would look like this:

```
<DrawerLayout>

    <LinearLayout> (or other type of layout)
        <Toolbar/>
        <content container/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Navigation Drawer/>

</DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: thank you for your help. i fixed it by doing somewhat similar :)